# Big bitmap in drawable-mdpi doesn’t show up

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, drawable

I’m testing an app on a Samsung S4 (441dpi=xxhdpi).
There is only one drawable folder, that I name drawable-mdpi, where I put a jpeg file of size 1600x898.
When I try to visualize it on an ImageView it doesn’t show up, while on a 213dpi tablet everything is ok. Furthermore on S4 if the image is smaller it is visualized.
Is it normal? From what I read on the documentation I expected that Android looked into other folders until it got a bitmap to be adapted.

> The system uses the appropriate alternative resource.   Based on the
>   size and density of the current screen, the system uses any size- and
>   density-specific resource provided in your application. For example,
>   if the device has a high-density screen and the application requests a
>   drawable resource, the system looks for a drawable resource directory
>   that best matches the device configuration. Depending on the other
>   alternative resources available, a resource directory with the hdpi
>   qualifier (such as drawable-hdpi/) might be the best match, so the
>   system uses the drawable resource from this directory.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Here we go again: downvoted after a few seconds by some Android god, without giving a reason. I don't think it is fair, if you think there is something wrong about the question, please explain it. I think I've carefully read other questions on SO and I've been not able to find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio IDE it shows drawable folder, but check in your project structure(means in your pc(where your project exist)). There it shows drawable along with all drawable folders(i.e mdpi,hdfi,xhdpi,xxhdpi).
This structure looks like shown below.

Driver(C or D..etc):\YourProjectName\app\src\main\res

Comment: The problem doesn't stem from the folders not being shown up, but from the bitmap in drawable-mdpi not being displayed on the ImageView.

Comment: The image(which is in folder drawable-mdpi) copy into drawable folder, then run application. It will work.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: is your image in drawable folder or drawable-mdpi?

Answer (score 0):

I had also same question before some time.

For that I create one test application.
I create 5 different size images with all different color.

- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-xxhdpi

And I run application in **Samsung Tab** , **Samsung S4**, **Samsung S3**, **Moto X Play**, **HTC Incredible** and some 2 othe device.

I notice that In all device Image display in different color.

That happen because all device is in different dimension.

The Drawables use for support  multiple screen size.

So if you want to same image in multiple screen you need to re-size image in multiple dimension.

Use follow site to convert image in multi dimension.

https://resizeappicon.com/

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: I finally will go for a solution like this, but is there a reason why images in drawable-mdpi cannot be adapted when they are large?

Comment: @GinoStrato Which solution?

Comment: The one with different drawable folders. In that way it works. But with just the one folder drawable-mdpi it doesn't and I cannot understand why.